# Is there standard of debug mode compilation flag in C compiler?

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-construction, standards, compiler-flags

Is there any pre-defined flag by standard specification (ANSI/C89/C99) for debug-mode-compilation in C compiler?

I know `DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` flags, but I am not sure about whether they're in the C standard or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on what you call - "debug mode compilation". It can mean lots of different things to different people:

1. no optimizations, so code can be more easily debugged
2. debug symbol generation, again to help debugger
3. usage of `assert` function
4. compiling with debug libraries, that do additional runtime checking
5. usage of other custom debugging techniques

The `NDEBUG` controls the bullet #3 only. Of course it is often combined with others, because it makes sense to use them together. But nothing forces you to use all of them - you may define various combinations of these things, e.g. optimized build with assert checks, etc.

Comment: It looks there is *no unified concept* of *debugging mode* in C standard. Did I understood correctly?

Comment: correct. debugging is environment-specific, not covered by standard

Answer (score 3):

No -- whether `NDEBUG` is defined or not is used in the standard to determine what `assert` expands to, but there's nothing about what causes it to be defined. At least to my recollection, there's nothing about anything named `DEBUG` at all.